# How to sort object's array with function pointer and template?

Tags: c++

*Here is my test code:*

```
template<typename T>
void sort(Result* n_obj, int n, bool (*cmp)(T d,T f)){
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j<n; j++){
            if((*cmp)(d,f)){
                swap(n_obj[i],n_obj[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Here is my problem - I get this output:*

```
In function 'void sort(Result*, int, bool (*)(T, T))':
[Error] 'f' was not declared in this scope
```

***why 'f' was not declared?***

**Note:** don't care about 'swap' function

Comment: Why do you use a function pointer and not `std::function`? Why do you use an array pointer and not `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Also, as a new user here, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: a function pointer it make my code look clean. Ex: `sort(R, n, DESC);`. I haven't learnt C++ STL yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the generic function arguments of the function pointer as arguments. That makes no sense. You need to specify them:

```
template<typename T>
void sort(Result* n_obj, int n, bool (*cmp)(T,T), T d, T f){
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(cmp(d,f)){
                std::swap(n_obj[i],n_obj[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You probably want to do this:

```
template<typename T>
void sort(Result* n_obj, int n, bool (*cmp)(T,T)){
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(cmp(n_obj[i], n_obj[j])){
                std::swap(n_obj[i],n_obj[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that being said, think about using `std::function` and `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of C-style syntax, if you want to work with `C++`. There's not really an argument to mix the two distinct languages.